# Material-table for react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I use material-ui for my project. And for data tables I use material-table. material-ui basic table has prop "stickyHeader" which fixes the table header while scrolling table body. I need the same thing for material-table but I can not find anything like it.

I tried to do it with custom css but my table becomes dependant on the layout. Is there any simple solution to have fixed footer and header for my material-table ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781114/changing-the-style-of-actions-in-material-table-react) helped me out as far as styling the bottom goes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use options.maxBodyHeight to make material-table sticky header. But there is no solution for fixed footer for now.

```js
 options={{
        maxBodyHeight: 200
      }}
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the footer color? I would like to make it the same as my toolbar